# Java - Collection of generic classes, each with a different generic type

Tags: java, generics

Suppose you have the following:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Foo<A> {
  A a;
}
```

and you have the following:

```
Foo<String> fooString = new Foo<>("abc");
Foo<Integer> fooInteger = new Foo<>(10);

List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
foos.add(fooString);
foos.add(fooInteger);
```

And I want to loop over the list of foos

```
for (Foo foo : foos) {
    ...
}
```

First of all, is there a different way of accomplishing this?

Then, how do I reference the generic type of each foo object inside the list? I tried with a wildcard but I'm encountering a compilation error "capture#1-of-? ..."

Comment: "Then, how do I reference the generic type of each foo object inside the list" <- Why do you want to do this? What is your goal here? As for a different way of acomplishing this: Since your Foo class doesn't really do much I don't see why you don't just use a List<Object>.

Comment: When you use `Foo` by itself, you're using a *raw* generic. Don't do that. In order for the list to contain both `Foo<String>` and `Foo<Integer>`, declare it as `List<Foo<?>>`. The loop should then be `for (Foo<?> foo : foos)`, and you now have the normal problem everyone has when building a mixed list: You don't know the type of each value with calling `instanceof`. You therefore need code like `if (foo.getA() instanceof String) { ... }` inside the loop, which is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

The following works because in your case you know that the foo types can only be either Integer or String and these are final classes assuming that `Foo.a` is never ```null``:

```
Foo<String> stringFoo = ...;
Foo<Integer> integerFoo = ...;

List<Foo<?>> allFoos = new ArrayList<>();
allFoos.add(stringFoo);
allFoos.add(integerFoo);

for (Foo<?> foo : allFoos) {
   if (foo.a instanceof Integer) {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked");
      Foo<Integer> intFoo = (Foo<Integer>) foo;
      //...
   } else if (foo.a instanceof String) {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      Foo<String> strFoo = (Foo<String>) str;
      //...
   } else {
      throw new IllegalStateException("this cannot happen");
   }
}
```

However in general this won't work if `allFoos` could be populated with arbitrary Foo types (not know in compilation-time) ... once you mix them all in the same bag/list you loose the ability to figure them out the type that was use in the instantiation code. You could assume that this is the same as the non-null `Foo.a` member instance but that is not necessarily the case:

```
// assuming constructor defined as Foo(A a) { this.a = a };
Foo<Number> one = new Foo<>((double) 100);
Foo<Double> two = new Foo<>(100);

Foo<?> oneUnknown = one;
Foo<?> twoUnknown = two;
```

You would perhaps end up saying that both are `Foo<Double>` but `one` was `Foo<Number>` when was constructed. In this case because `Foo` is very simple class it might not make a difference but if it had more complex operations perhaps it would.